# Linux From Scratch: Error while compiling binutils 2.32

Tags: linux, compiling, compiler, binutils

I am working on [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) and currently, I am on [this page](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter05/binutils-pass1.html). While compiling [binutils-2.32](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), I am getting this error:

```
lfs@pop-os:/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-2.32/build$ ../configure --prefix=/tools            \
>              --with-sysroot=$LFS        \
>              --with-lib-path=/tools/lib \
>              --target=$LFS_TGT          \
>              --disable-nls              \
>              --disable-werror
../configure: line 1345: cd: /mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-2.32/build: Not a directory
configure: error: working directory cannot be determined
lfs@pop-os:/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-2.32/build$
```

As you can see from the prompt, `build` is a directory. Still, it shows the error that it is not a directory. I tried to understand the code at line 1345 of configure file but unable to understand. What mistake I did in this process?

Comment: Posted as text.

Comment: Did you do anything between the `cd build` step and the `configure` step?  What if you do `cd .` and then run `configure` again?

Comment: Looks like the build directory has been deleted since you entered it.

Comment: What OS and shell are you using?

Comment: @jordanm : build directory is still there.

Comment: @Kusalananda : same error.

Comment: Are you using any special filesystem, like bind mounts or union filesystems, or NFS or something else that would make the build directory inaccessible or make it show up as a file instead of a directory if accessing it in the wrong way?

Comment: @Kusalnanda : It is EXT4.

Comment: I only know one way to produce this behaviour but ot is so arcane that I have a hard time believing you did it accidentally. All the same, it would be useful to know exactly how you created the `build` directory.

Comment: @rici : mkdir -v build

Comment: Ok. What happens when you are in the directory and you type `cd "$(pwd)"`?

Comment: @rici : Permission denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a permissions problem. Most likely somewhere in the path `/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-2.32/build`, there is directory which lacks `x` permission for the user you are using. (It might also lack `r` permission; it should have both.) This is usually the result of creating as directory as `root`.

Comment: Yes, user lacked permission on the lfs folder. Rectified it, now its working.